# Логика RESTfull API

Tags: php, yii2, api, vue.js, rest

Интересует общепринятый принцип построения RESTful API. В качестве бекэнда использовать планирую yii2 standart. Поставил сейчас свежую версию через композер, убрал web из адресной строки с помощью .htaccess.

Я представлял себе API как action класса, который возвращает нужные данные. Скажем, в БД есть таблица с данными о Клиентах и таблицах с данными о их Обращениях. Прикидывал, что можно сделать action, который бы сразу же вернул бы мне в одном json данные клиента и его обращения. Но если посмотреть на документацию yii2, то там есть примеры только по типу "одна модель - один action". Т.е. чтобы получить мне данные о клиенте и его обращениях мне нужно сделать два запроса на сервер. А если цепочка таблиц будет больше, то и запросов придётся сделать столько же. И потом это всё крутить-парсить на стороне vue.js.

Так как всё же правильно? Модель-action? Или же можно делать совмещённые action, которые возвращают данные сразу от нескольких моделей. Или может что-то другое? Быть может есть ещё какие-то подходы? Советы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дока http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-resources.html

Можно в одном запросе выводить данные о клиенте и его сообщениях. Есть два способа такой реализации:

1. В модели `users` метод `fields` возвращает связь с таблицей `messages`

   ```
   class Users extends ActiveRecord
   {
       public function fields()
       {
           return [
               'id',
               'name',
               'messages' => 'messages',
          ];
       }

       public function getMessages()
       {
           return $this->hasMany(Messages::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Передавать специальный `get` параметр `expand`
   (`http://localhost/user?expand=messages`). В этом случаи в модели
   должен быть метод `extraFields`

   ```
   class Users extends ActiveRecord
   {
       public function fields()
       {
           return [
               'id',
               'name',
          ];
       }

       public function extraFields()
       {
           return [
               'messages',
           ];
       }

       public function getMessages()
       {
           return $this->hasMany(Messages::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: А если вложенность древовидная? Например, У клиента есть обращения, у обращений есть заказы, у заказов есть ещё несколько связанных таблиц, у каждой из которых тоже есть свои связи? Само собой для каждой такой таблицы есть своя модель и описаны связи. Реально ли одним запросом вытянуть сразу все данные? В вашем примере я получу данные только из таблицы\модели Message. А если в модели Message также описана связь с другой таблицей, заданы fields() и extraFields(), получу ли я и данных из третьей таблицы?

Answer (score 1):

Совет простой: не использовать ActiveController.
Используйте обычный yii\rest\Controller, в конфиге приложения укажите:

```
    'request' => [
        'parsers' => [
            'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
        ],
```

И формируйте данные как вам удобно. Без эктив рэкорда или с ним, это вообще не важно.

Comment: а как с масштабируемостью при таком подходе? И если не использовать наследование от ActiveController, то ведь тогда не будут созданы автоматически POST, GET, PUT и т.д., нет?

Comment: Естественно не будут. Делайте руками только то что вам нужно.